# How to store geometry point in Oracle using java with hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I need to store a POINT in Oracle, and I don't know what type to use. First, I tried String (using the format POINT(123, 456) because that's the format Oracle shows me. But it didn't work.

I have this class:

```
package model;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="teste")
public class Test {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="timestamp")
    private Timestamp timestamp;

    @Column(name="geometry")
    private String point; // <-- I don't know which type to use here.

// constructors, getters and setters
}
```

Does someone know what's the correct type here?

EDIT: I've followed the tutorial indicated by @Zia and now, I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.hibernate.spatial.GeometrySqlTypeDescriptor.getBinder(GeometrySqlTypeDescriptor.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2843)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3121)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
```

One thing that I added to the code was:

```
@Column(name="geometry", columnDefinition="SDO_GEOMETRY")
@Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
private String point;
```

But I don't know if I have to use `SDO_GEOMETRY` or `GEOMETRY`. Both are giving me the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
```

its from hibernate spatial api..
for more details have look into below link

http://www.hibernatespatial.org/

http://www.hibernatespatial.org/documentation/02-Tutorial/01-tutorial4/

Dont forget to add the SpatialDialect in your configuration file.for Mysql it would be like

```
org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatialDialect
```

Comment: Could you please see the EDIT in my quesiton?

Comment: do you have all the required spatial jar in your classpath and dialect entry in your hibernate configuration file?.Please add the spatial dialect in your hibernate configuration file for the database whichever your using and try it for MYSQL dialect its like .e g org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatialDialect

Comment: here its reference for the dialect http://www.hibernatespatial.org/documentation/03-dialects/03-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

The best is to use two columns x and y and save the coordinates of the point

```
@Column(name="x")
private int x; 

@Column(name="y")
private int y;
```

Saving the point in two different coordinates will give you:

- easy access to coordinates without parsing them
- easy build to queries like find all points left to the origin (0, 0)
- possibility to add indexes on x and y to find points faster

---

Spatial types of oracle are not standard types so there is no equivalent mapping to a java type as for INT, DATE, VARCHAR or similar.

To map to it you need to use the java type `JGeometryType`. Here a nice [tutorial](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2007/02/05/using-hibernate-with-oracle-spatial/) to do that.